# How to access app name from within blueprint template?

Tags: flask

I've written a common blueprint for a bunch of independent little apps as a python package. Mostly this is just a top-level template and a style sheet to give the apps a unified design. I'd like to display the current app's name in the top-level template, but I have no idea how. It seems that there is no way to get to the app context from within the blueprint that the app registered.

I've tried this:

```
@blueprint.context_processor
def appinfo():
    return { 'appname': flask.current_app.name }
```

but it only works when the template is rendered by one of the blueprint's view functions but not from the app's.

Answer (score 4):

blueprint.app_context_processor() does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`Blueprint.context_processor` decorator](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/1.0.2/flask/blueprints.py#L365) implies that the function will be called only for requests handled by the blueprint. Namespaces are great!

If you'd like 'appname' to be available in every template: app and blueprints alike, registering the context processor with `Flask.context_processor` should satisfy that.

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.context_processor
def appinfo():
    return dict(appname=app.name)
```

Comment: I know that I can use the context_processor in every app, but  I was hoping to somehow do it only once in the blueprint.

Comment: Okay, you will need to figure out a way to get the Flask instance in the blueprint package. May expose a factory function in the blueprint package that takes the Flask instance and uses it in the blueprint to define the context processor. As is, there is an explicit dependency on the Flask instance

Comment: You can use bluprint.context_processor and it is scoped to the blueprint or blueprint.app_context_processor then the context is available in the entire app